# What is the word "Self" in this sentence

Tags: grammaticality

> The product has been delivered to **self** John.

What is the word self in this context?

Is it adjective or pronoun.

Explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it doesn't seem to be serving any function at all. It is not being used correctly. It should not be in the sentence. Self can be an adjective or a noun but it's not serving as either one here. Remove "self" and the sentence is fine.

Comment: So, this sentence is not grammatical at all?

Comment: @Kumarsadhu It's perfectly grammatical if you remove the word "self."

Comment: But how to emphasize the fact that I have delivered the parcel to the same person who had ordered

Comment: ... to John *himself*.

Comment: @Kumarsadhu Yes, that's correct. In that case, "himself" is an emphatic pronoun.